# why does the output print JdbcOdbcConnection

Tags: java, jdbc

Why does the output print- JdbcOdbcConnection but the return type is a connection object

```
import java.sql.*;
import sun.jdbc.odbc.*;

class JdbcEx3
{

       public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
       {
             Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
             Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:mysql1","root","root123");

             System.out.println(con);
       }
}
```

Comment: Because `getConnection` doesn't return a `JdbcOdbcConnection`. Check the API docs.

Comment: then is it wrong to say that it returns a class object

Answer (score 0):

Since the variable you have declared is of type  JdbcOdbcConnection and same is not returned from the method DriverManager so it is necessary to typecast the object.

Answer (score 0):

`DriverManager.getConnection()` methdo returns you Connection [Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#getConnection%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Properties%29) and not JdbcOdbcConnection and hence you need to typecast here if you are sure, your driver is going to return an instance of JdbcOdbcConnection else you would get ClassCastException.

Answer (score 0):

`DriverManager.getConnection` returns the `Connection` interface, so I can't assign it directly to a `JdbcOdbcConnection` instance. Hence. you either have to cast, or, preferably, just use the interface:

```
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:mysql1","root","root123");
System.out.println(con);
```